# What does "size" mean in memory cache

Tags: node.js, caching, lru

I am asking from a NodeJS standpoint and specifically for [lru-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache), but the question should apply broadly. Almost every memory cache manager I could find refers to "size", "maxSize" or something similar but never mentions what kind of unit that is. Is it a number of key/value pairs? Is it a number in bytes? Or something else entirely?

An additional question would be how would I calculate the amount of memory one key/value takes up? For example:
`('key', {name: 'John', age: '55'})`

**Side note**: *not sure if this is relevant, but the reason I am asking is that I want to calculate theoretical cache limits with the available resources that my environment has. And after I know the theoretical limit I can do a practical one to see if it maps on and get the actual limit.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with a cache the size is usually in bytes. For example redis has a max key/value size of 512mb by default:
https://linuxhint.com/redis-max-key-length/

For your use-case it's a little bit different since lru-cache has a method you can define for the sizeCalculation:
https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache#sizecalculation

To calculate the size of an object like `{name: 'John', age: '55'}` in bytes you could do the following in NodeJS:

```
sizeCalculation: (value, key) => {
  return Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(value))
},
```

Comment: I noticed you only measured byte length for the value, wouldn't it be more accurate to `return Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(value+key))`?

Comment: Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(value) + key)